# Unable to Load Dependent SO file in LInux

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, loading, tesseract

I am new to linux. I am trying to load a SO file in Ubuntu using Java. The file that I have specified in the java method "System.load(/home/ab/Downloads/libtesseract.so)" loads fine but its dependent so file placed in the same place as "libtesseract.so" is not found. Here is the error message I get. Error: UnSatisfiedLinkError and says "liblept.so.4" cound not be found. This so file is placed in the same location as libtesseract.so. When I place "liblept.so.4" in the "/lib". It is able to load this so file from. So what I understood is that for, its not for java to load the dependent so. It has to be loaded by ubuntu. So I tried a simple application to load this by setting the PATH variable with the location of the so file. And exported the java code into a jar and tried to run this jar file from terminal as the path variable is not persistent for entire system. It worked fine. So I tried to do the same thing programmatically by using the code below to its not working. Please advice. TIA

Code:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh");
    Map<String, String> envMap = pb.environment();
    envMap.put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "/home/ab/Downloads");
    envMap.put("PATH", "/home/ab/Downloads");
    Set<String> keys = envMap.keySet();
    for(String key:keys)
    {
        System.out.println(key+" ==> "+envMap.get(key));
    }
    System.load("/home/ab/Downloads/libtesseract.so");
```

Comment: "So what I understood is that for, its not for java to load the dependent so. It has to be loaded by ubuntu." - No, I believe this is the job of the JVM to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Damien...Why I say this is because the First or main SO that I am loading using java code loads fine but when this Main SO looks for other Dependent So, It fails when that other dependent so is present in the same location.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't really modify the environment variables in Java "on-the-fly". That means you should set both LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH before running the java.

Comment: You can't set it in code. You should change the environments before running the program

Comment: Hi, sorry, I deleted my previous comment. I got your point. But that is not possible since I have these So files bundled in my jar that I unjar on the fly and need to use these from the place I unjar.

Comment: Soft link to the folder that in path after unjarring?

Comment: Yes, I unjar them to /tmp/.... and then need to set this location of SO for my program. But to this, I must be able to set that location to PATH variable.

Comment: Add /tmp to LD_LIBRARY_PATH then. Or add some /tmp/libs and make a softlinks for the unjared so into this folder. The idea is that the folder should be in environment before the execution.

Comment: @Roman..Please excuse me if I have not understood you correctly. I have tried to add the /tmp... path after unjarring using "envMap.put" code shown in the main question. Then I try to load but the error message continues. Please comment if this is not what you meant me to try.

Comment: You can't do it from code. Run setenv from bash and run the program *after* the environment was set. You can't change the environmennt at runtime

Comment: Thanks Roman.. I think it got your point. I will now may be make a script to have all this available before the java code starts running.